# Asp.Net Core 6 Add Bootstrap to scaffolded Identity _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I am using VS2022 Preview and have created a Single Page Application using Angular and the default project in VS2022.  I have scaffolded the Identity pages so that I can change the styles by overriding bootstrap with one from Bootswatch.  However, when I try to reference bootstrap from my lib folder in wwwroot like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Then I get the error:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://localhost:5002/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

I've tried various file paths here but nothing seems to work.  Any help would be great as this seems like a trivial task!

Comment: Bootstrap is used by default in an ASP.NET Core SPA, so why do you need to add  it again? Isn't it *already* added in `index.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_Layout.cshtml` page is generated by Scaffolded Identity, right?

If that is case, the Identity package also contains the Bootstrap reference, and by default the `_Layout.cshtml` page already adds the bootstrap reference using the following code, you could consider using it as a workaround.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

The result as below:

[image]

Besides, you could also try to use CDN reference:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please move your lib folder to wwwroot folder and reference it from there.